# how to code a circle that changes color when clicked in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanna change the color of my circle between red and green when someone clicks on the circle. Both the colors should randomly switch. For Example when someone clicks on a red circle it can switch to green color or stay red and vice versa.(R,R,G,G,G,G,R.....)

The demo currently looks like this. https://jsfiddle.net/sidsingh29/591hfwLd/12/

```
HTML:
<div id="test"></div>

CSS:

#test {
    position:absolute;
    height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;}


JavaScript + jQuery (edge):

$('#test').click(function() {
    var docHeight = $(document).height(),
        docWidth = $(document).width(),
        $div = $('#test'),
        divWidth = $div.width(),
        divHeight = $div.height(),
        heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
        widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;
    
    $div.css({
        left: Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax ),
        top: Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax )
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a reaction testing game, like in the "Complete Web Developer Course 2.0" that you can purchase on udemy.com?

Answer (score 0):

Just set `background` property also with `left` and `top` based on `Math.random() > 0.5` or not:

```js
$('#test').click(function() {
      var docHeight = $(document).height(),
        docWidth = $(document).width(),
        $div = $('#test'),
        divWidth = $div.width(),
        divHeight = $div.height(),
        heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
        widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;
    
      $div.css({
        left: Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax ),
        top: Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax ),
        background: Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'red' : 'green', // setting background here
      });
    });
```

```css
#test {
    position:absolute;
    height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This task cannot be done using entirely CSS, so I have used Javascript and jQuery to do it. Sometimes it can keep the same colour over and over, because I am using random generated numbers to change the colour. I have also put in a timer that times the time you take to click on the circle, in case you were making a reaction tester.

```js
var colour = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

function oddOrEven(x) {
  return ( x & 1 ) ? "odd" : "even";
}

function checkNumber(argNumber) {
  var result = oddOrEven(argNumber);
  if (result == "even") {

    $("#circle").css("background-color", "red");
  
  } else {

    $("#circle").css("background-color", "green");

  };
  start = new Date().getTime();
}

$(document).ready(function() { 

  checkNumber(colour) 
  
});

function makeShapeAppear() {

   var docHeight = $(document).height(),
      docWidth = $(document).width(),
      circle = $('#circle'),
      circleWidth = circle.width(),
      circleHeight = circle.height(),
      heightMax = docHeight - circleHeight,
      widthMax = docWidth - circleWidth;
    
  circle.css({
    left: Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax ),
    top: Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax ),
    display: "block",
  });
  
  colour = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  checkNumber(colour)

};

$('#circle').click(function() {

  makeShapeAppear();

});
        
document.getElementById("circle").onclick = function() {
            
  document.getElementById("circle").style.display = "none";

  var end = new Date().getTime();

  var timeTaken = (end - start) / 1000;

  document.getElementById("timeTaken").innerHTML = timeTaken + " seconds taken";
            
}
```

```css
#circle {

  height: 100px; 
  width: 100px;
  border: 0x solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="circle" onclick="makeShapeAppear()"></div>
<h3>Time Taken = </h3><div id="timeTaken"></div>
```

Comment: this is amazing. Thank you, I actually was looking to use a timer. Great spot!!